# Progressive build animation organic mesh solutions

Tags: animation, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I search many solution to make a progressive organic meshing like this exemple :

[image]

I have explore solutions with :

1. curve (start/end mapping)
2. array (fit curve) caps round and modifier curve
3. boolean (with shape keys animation)
4. Weight Proximity with geometry node

But none of them seems to be the best solution.

Maybe its possible to make better thing with geometry node, more easily animated, but i don't know how.

Let's see how best to do this.

Comment: It looks like perhaps the drug is being boolean-ed, and then there’s a subdivision surface modifier on it.

Comment: Yes it's like this for simple solution but it's very long and not comfortable to anime this...

Comment: what do you mean? The Boolean modifier works in real time. All you have to do is animate the molecule moving towards and away from a concave surface which acts as the cutter.

Comment: Interesting question. How do you get weights, or some other attribute, to diffuse down the topology of a branched mesh....